# front page design: scalable container of 6 link-tiles

Tags: html, css

I am designing the front page for my blog. I found some difficulties with proper display and css formatting. Namely symmetric placement and  of images and display on different resolutions.

**So what i want to achieve:**

The container with 6 link-tiles (like in chrome), where each tile is link to the website, and each tile is composed of two parts: title and photo. 
something like chrome window display.

Tiles are display with auto margin, symmetrically ( auto margin and padding) at different @media as follows.

- Desktop and Tablet  -  2 rows x 3 columns
- Mobile  - 3 rows x 2 columns

[See photo for end result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3B4mc.png)

My initial try is as follows -

```css
#btiles {
  margin: 5px 1px;
  padding: 2px;
}

#btiles a {
  margin: 10px auto;
  padding 0;
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 32%;
  /* 3 tiles in one row and some space around */
  max-width: 200px;
  /* photos are 250px x 250px */
}

@media (max-width: 480px) {
  #btiles a {
    width: 50%;
    min-width: 150px;
  }
  /* 2 tiles in one row and some space around - photos are 250px x 250px */
}

#btiles img {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.bv-tile,
.bv-empty-tile {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: transparent;
  border: 1px solid #e1e8ed;
  border-radius: 6px;
  z-index: 10;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: center;
}

.bv-title {
  background: grey;
  height: 30px;
  overflow: elipis;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px auto;
  width: 100%;
  vertical-align: center;
  color: #002268;
  font-family: Open Sans Condensed;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  font-variant: small-caps;
}

.bv-thumb {
  background: white;
  margin: 0;
  border-radius: 0 0 6px 6px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

#btiles img {
  filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns=\'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\'><filter id=\'old-timey\'><feColorMatrix type=\'matrix\' values=\'0.14 0.45 0.05 0 0 0.12 0.39 0.04 0 0 0.08 0.28 0.03 0 0 0 0 0 1 0\'/></filter></svg>#old-timey");
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(1);
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
  -moz-filter: grayscale(100%);
  -ms-filter: grayscale(100%);
  -o-filter: grayscale(100%);
  filter: grayscale(100%);
}

#btiles img:hover {
  filter: none;
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(0);
  -moz-filter: grayscale(0);
  -ms-filter: grayscale(0);
  -o-filter: grayscale(0);
  filter: grayscale(0);
}
```

```html
<div id="btiles" style="opacity: 1;">
  <!—tiles container -->
  <!—tile 1-->
  <a class="bv-tile" href="https://www.my.blog /link-1" title="Filed-1">
    <!—title 1-->
    <div class="bv-title">Filed-1</div>
    <!—image 1-->
    <div class="bv-thumb"><img title=" Filed-1-img" src="https://www. my.blog /wp-content/uploads/field-1.png"></div>
  </a>
  <!—tile 2-->
  <a class="bv-tile" href=" https://www.my.blog /link-2 /" title=" Filed-2 ">
    <div class="bv-title"> Filed-2 </div>
    <div class="bv-thumb"><img title=" Filed-2-img" src=" https://www. my.blog /wp-content/uploads/field-2.png "></div>
  </a>
  <!—tile 3-->
  <!—tile 4-->
  <!—tile 5-->
  <!—tile 6-->
</div>
<!—end of btiles -->
```

I am beginner so still learn.
Thank you for you help.

Comment: What issue are you facing currently? Can you be more specific?

Comment: tiles (images ) float to the left .